# Count from order group by last status

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I want to count last_status from history. Here is it a table looks like

```
--------
p_table
--------
id
name

----------------
history_p_table
----------------
id
p_id (many to one p_table)
status_id (many to one status_table)
date_history
order_history

------------
status_table
------------
id
name
```

`p_table` `hasMany` `history_table` and `history_table` `belongsto` `status_table`
I want to get all count of **status** from last_status (get last_status, the first status order by date_history DESC, order_history DESC and history.id DESC) history p_table (count group by last_status)

I've tried with SQL but it still getting error

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT status_id FROM history_p
    LEFT JOIN status_table ON status_table.id=history_p.status_id
    LEFT JOIN p ON history_p.p_id=p.id
    GROUP BY status_id, p_id
    ORDER BY date_history DESC, order_history DESC, history_p.id DESC) AS last_status,
    ss.*, COUNT(last_status) FROM status_table ss
    LEFT JOIN status_table su ON su.id=ss.id
    GROUP BY last_status
```

Here is it the P model

```
class P extends Model{
  public function statusNow(){
        return $this->historyPs()
            ->orderBy('date_history','DESC')
            ->orderBy('order_history', 'DESC')
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->first();
  }

  public function historyPs()
  {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\HistoryP::class);
  }
}
```

Here is it the HistoryP model

```
class HistoryP extends Model
{
    public function status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Status::class);
    }

    public function p()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\P::class);
    }
}
```

Is there the best way to do this? I need it to eloquent but if there is no way and should using raw query not problem too
Here is it the sample data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73709c

I need to get

```
-------------------
Get Packet   | 2
Send to Cust | 0 
Send to P    | 10
Sent to Pab  | 1
-------------------
```

Comment: can you provide models in question

Comment: Either create online fiddle or provide CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO with some sample data, and provide desired output for this data.

Comment: Thank you for your recomendation, here is it the sql https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pJZnKnsed4JqzVW7h3HnKh/1 . Need help @Strawberry